# brew install gettext, should i force link it?

Tags: homebrew, django, gettext

I am doing some web development and the translation engine requires gettext. Should I force link it?

```
$ django-admin.py makemessages -l es
CommandError: Can't find xgettext. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.

$ brew install gettext
Warning: gettext-0.18.3.2 already installed

$ brew link gettext
Warning: gettext is keg-only and must be linked with --force
Note that doing so can interfere with building software.
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

same problem here, just run

```
brew link gettext --force
```

and

```
manage.py compilemessages
```

and everything working fine. you can always

```
brew unlink gettext
```

if you have problems and revert back to previous state

Comment: now i get Warning: Some keg-only formula are linked into the Cellar.
Linking a keg-only formula, such as gettext, into the cellar with
`brew link <formula>` will cause other formulae to detect them during
the `./configure` step. This may cause problems when compiling those
other formulae.

Binaries provided by keg-only formulae may override system binaries
with other strange results.

You may wish to `brew unlink` these brews:

    gettext

Comment: hey @broinjc there's no harm in the warning you are receiving, it's highly unlikely that you'll need to compile other packages based on the ones you have already installed. one problem at a time, ok? ;)

Comment: yes one problem at a time ;) haha.

Comment: I think saying "just run `... --force`" is dangerous, and should also hint as to when this ok. People coming here might actually end up having to compile packages where this can produce issues.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running this `brew link gettext --force`, but I was getting:

```
$ brew install gettext
Warning: gettext 0.20.2 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 0.20.2, run `brew reinstall gettext`

$ brew link gettext --force
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: gettext
If you need to have gettext first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find gettext you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include"
```

Then, I just added it to the system path with:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/gettext/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Related:

1. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299048/can-not-use-the-gettext-which-is-installed-by-brew
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670295/homebrew-refusing-to-link-openssl
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940383/how-to-install-gettext-on-macos-x
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422345/installed-just-not-linked
5. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644349/msgmerge-on-macos-catalina